# Precise definition of a limit: Why is the delta chosen to be 1 and not \sqrt{2}-1

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

We have the following limit to prove using delta-epsilon

$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x+1}{1+\sqrt{x}}$

It can be manipulated into

$|x-1| |\sqrt{x}-1||\frac{1}{{(1+\sqrt{x})}^{2}}|<\varepsilon$

if our next step is to replicate
$\sqrt{x}-1$   in

$-1<|x-1|<1$

should it not be

$0<|\sqrt{x}-1|<\sqrt{2}-1$

instead of the given answer of $0<|\sqrt{x}-1|<1$ ?

[Problem and given solution here.](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preclimsoldirectory/PrecLimSol.html#SOLUTION%2012)

Comment: What is the correct numerator, the $x+1$ here or the $x+3$ in the linked document? Or are you trying to solve a different problem?

Comment: How can that limit be manipulated into$$|x-1|\left|\sqrt x-1\right|\frac1{1+\sqrt x}?$$You have$$\left|\frac{x+1}{1+\sqrt x}-1\right|=\sqrt x\left|\sqrt x-1\right|\frac1{1+\sqrt x}.$$

Comment: You are correct I made a typo. It is corrected now.

Comment: you can observe $\sqrt{2}-1<1$